# WCF can not access remote configuration settings (ConnectionString)

Tags: wcf, configuration, remoting

My WCF service writes into a database. The configuration settings (here specifically the connectionstring) are brought from an internal application (probably over remoting). It works when I use local settings for connectionString, but fails when accessing connectionstring from our internal application.

The wcf service call goes through fine, but the code breaks at the point where my connection string value is fetched.

Errors: 
1)On a higher level the client.operationcontract(params) throws: 'Access Denied' error.

2)
i)And internally, the configuration-fetching-function throws a vague: "The Key Configuration.ActivatorString does not exist in the appSettings configuration section"
ii) the dllxxx.bWebSvcMode threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' (this is the dll which is used to access the configuration settings

Is this a problem in the way I am using wcf?

Comment: is the connection string in your primary config file? are you reading it form a different config file? if yes, Are you able to read other settings?

Comment: I figured out that the "Configuration.Activator" key had to be added in the WCF project app.config file. This fixed the issue.  Thanks @Dhawalk, overall it was indeed about having your configurations/connectionstrings specified properly, and making them available in your WCF project.